# Evitar bloqueo de CORS por método PUT

Tags: django, cors, django-views, react-axios

**Problema**: Estoy intentando realizar una petición de tipo `PUT` para modificar datos de una `API REST` en `django`, pero una vez configurado el método `PUT` dentro de `views.py` al realizar la petición obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error en la consola del navegador:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/Jugadores/0'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
> Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

## `Views.py`

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def api_update_jugadores(request, slug):
    
    try:
        usuario_var = USUARIO.objects.get(slug = slug)
    except USUARIO.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = UsuariosSerializer(usuario_var, data = request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            data['success'] = 'update successful'
            return Response(data=data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
        


class UsuarioView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    search_fields = ['nombre']
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    serializer_class = UsuariosSerializer
    queryset = USUARIO.objects.all()
```

## Código de la petición

```
  async buttonHandler(jugador) {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/Jugadores/' + jugador.id;
    jugador.usuario_equipo = 2;
    await axios.put(url, jugador);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo solucionan [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357687/django-python-rest-framework-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present), intenta:

Instalar los paquetes cors necesarios:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

Agregala a tus apps instaladas en ``setting.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
```

También agregalo en MIDDLEWARE, **debe estar al principio de esta lista**:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [  
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Agrega esta configuración antes de INSTALLED_APPS:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True
```

O, alternativamente, crea una lista con todos los posibles *endpoints*:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://google.com',
    'http://hostname.example.com',
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:9000'
]
```